# Redefining C++ function using a struct

Tags: c++, struct

Let's say, I have the following in a "foo.hpp". I have a *function* with the same name as the *struct*.

```
int foo(int i);

struct foo{
 foo(int i){ value = i;}
 operator int() {return value;}
 int value;
};
```

If I call it in main like so:

```
int main()
{
 std::cout << foo(1) << std::endl; // function is called, not the struct, why??
}
```

Why does the compiler always link the function and not the struct? If possible, how to change that the struct is linked, not the function?

Ultimately, I would like to overwrite a function in a library by adding an extra header file and overwriting the function with the struct. That way, I am hoping to change one specific function, but continue using all other library functions and not alter the library code at the same time.

Comment: this is C++ code, please remove the 'C' tag.

Comment: although overloading of names is allowed in C++, overloading between a struct definition and a function name is a very bad idea.

Comment: How would you redefine one particular function in a library without altering the productive code nor library code?

Comment: How would the compiler know which to call actually if both have the same signature? Note: that is not a struct, but a class actually, regardless of the keyword. A struct is normally understood as a simple compound data type without methods.

Comment: Regarding the note: I agree. I am sometimes use struct instead of class if I want every member methods and variables to be public - maybe bad habit... anyway, regarding the same signature, yes, I dont know how the compiler will know which one to call. But I tried in MSVS 2010 and it seems it always picks the function.

Comment: What do you use to differentiate the name of the `struct`'s constructor?

Comment: I am not! I choose the same argument in the constructor as in the function on purpose. My question is whether or not it is somehow possible to call in the main same-named struct instead of the function.

Comment: Why the compiler picks the function I don't know, if I had to guess it is because it is ambiguous which to choose but the function call is the more sane option. You should just make your own function have a different name and use `#ifdef` or some other unambiguous method

Comment: @Ben You can place your code in a namespace and redifine needed functions inside. Compiler will peek closest definition available.

Comment: I still wonder why not just use a different name. Using the same name/signature for two different functions seems - well - unfavourable at best. Whoever has to maintain this code will likely be "thankful".

Comment: I understand what you mean - it might be the pragmatic solution. But my intention is to run the same productive code on different platforms. I have some library function that need to be altered depending on the platform. So the productive code needs just the correct header file to be included. And I do not want to alter the library code myself either, because in case of a newer version of the library, I need to make the whole changes there again.

Comment: Adaption to different platforms is normally not done by different headers, but different libraries. Or - if necessary - by conditional compilation. However - your project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Justification

According to the C++ standard [N4431](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf) *§ 3.3.10/2 Name hiding [basic.scope.hiding]* (**emphasis mine**):

***A class name*** (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) **can be hidden by the name of a** variable, data member,
**function,** or enumerator **declared in the same scope. If a class** or enumeration name and a variable, data
member, function, or enumerator are **declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the
class** or enumeration name **is hidden wherever the** variable, data member, **function,** or enumerator **name is
visible.**

### **Solution**

Put either `struct foo` or function `foo` in its own `namespace`.

Comment: @Olaf  A class name is shadowed by a function with the same name. "object"?

Comment: @Olaf During name look up we have just names (not objects) that belong to specific types (i.e., `class`, `enumeration`, `variable`, `data member`, `function` or `enumerator`). A name of a function shadows the name of a class with the same name. That's C++ name look up rules.

Comment: I do not refer to name lookup. I perfectly understand the background and what goes on. I just tried to summarize what the standard says. But apparently, there is no concept of "first/second class objects" (that is not the datatype `class`. Must be because C++ is only partially OO - different from full OOPLs like Smalltalk, Python (Ruby, I suppose, too) where classes are also objects. - Just forget it, I have no idea how to explain that; my English skills are apparently insufficient.

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you. I wasn't aware of name hiding until this point. Yes, ok, then I guess I need to use namespaces. I will try whether I can add <platform-name>::foo(..) in each call and reduce it again by adding using namespace=<platform-name>. Then I need some kind of mechanism that evaluates the platform-name (maybe pragma or something). Anyway, thank you for the information it was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot going on here.

When you have a function inside a struct that has the same name as the struct, that is a "constructor". It is called to fill in the member variables of the struct. In your case, the constructor, foo, assigns the value of "i" to the member variable "value".

Then in main you construct a struct foo object, giving it the value 1. In the context, the compiler discovers that you have provided a conversion operator to an int, which it uses to pass to the object to the stream.

So I'm not sure I understand where you think the struct should be linked instead of the function. You can call constructors to make objects. You can't actually call a struct. (unless you make an operator() in it, then you can call that member function of the struct. But you didn't make one of those, so there isn't a meaning to "calling the struct".)

As far as overriding library functions -- Do you have access to the code that you want to call your new function? It wouldn't be confusing to just change the call to be to your new function. If you have to change but can't change the source, you can (often) provide a new function with EXACTLY the same signature in the same set of object modules and it will be used before the linker finds the other version in a library. But what you want is a function, not a struct.

Comment: Yea, exactly. What I mean by "calling the struct", I was thinking of exactly your description. I want to 'simulate' a call function. Since the struct's constructor has the same argument, and returning the value by operator int(), it looks as if I am calling a function. So I thought myself, maybe I could redefine a function which is in a library this way.

Comment: Now regarding your question: yes, I have access to the library code. But I do not want to bother change a library code as it is a 3rd party code. Besides that, I want to be able to update the library when new versions arrive. So I was seeking a solution where I specifically pick a function to "redefine" it for each platform's characteristics. I think, the suggested namespace solution would do with some extra code lines.